# How to get clang-format to not join multiline calls into one line?

Tags: c++, coding-style, clang-format

For example, this code snippet:

```
{
    FooBar processor;

    processor
        .process(obj1)
        .process(someString)
        .process(anotherParameter);
}
```

is always translated to this:

```
{
    FooBar processor;

    processor.process(obj1).process(someString).process(anotherParameter);
}
```

So, it becomes less readable and not friendly from VCS point of view if I need to modify the chain in the middle.

Is there a way to prevent such `clang-format` behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In current version (clang-format 3.8) the only good ways to do this that I know of are:

```
{
    FooBar processor;

    processor //
        .process(obj1) //
        .process(someString) //
        .process(anotherParameter);
}
```

and

```
{
    FooBar processor;

    // clang-format off
    processor
        .process(obj1)
        .process(someString)
        .process(anotherParameter);
    // clang-format on
}
```